# How can I change the name of buttons on click of a button?

Tags: android, button, onclick

In my calculator app, I want an Inverse button, which when clicked changes the text of other buttons. Like sin to sin inverse etc. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but what have you tried so far, what is not working out for you? Please edit your question with more information because StackOverflow is not here to write the code for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just change the text of a button in that button onclick event.
Say For example

```
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            if(btn.getText().toString().trim().equals("sin")){
                btn.setText("sin inverse");
            }else if(btn.getText().toString().trim().equals("sin inverse")){
                btn.setText("sin");
            }

            }
        });
```

I think this will help you

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers are completely right showing you to how rename the buttons, I suggest another solution with a cleaner design: Have **different buttons** for "sin" and "sin inverse", and just **make them visible/invisible** when clicking the "Inverse" button. That way you can write clean click handlers and don't have to use a lot of "if (isInverseMode()...)".

To make that work correctly, you just declare some additional buttons for the inverse operations in your XML layout file and set them to `android:visibility="gone"`.

If you then set one the visible buttons to invisible and the next insivible button besides it to visible in the code, then the effect for the user looks like you exchanged one button by the other (so he only notices the text of the button changing).

Comment: I thought of mentioning this, but decided just to answer his question... although I did note that changing the text was not going to change the function.  :)

Comment: @Barak: You know the difference of giving a hungry guy asking for food just some fish or the alternative of giving him a fishing rod and teach him fishing? I prefer the second if I can afford it. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible.

Just re-set the button text in your onClick method for the button.

```
buttonId.setText("Your button text");
```

From what you're saying though it sounds like you want to change the buttons function as well as the text...  in which case you need to put an if statement in your onClick method to handle the two button states.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the text on a button would help anytime.

Answer (score -1):

This code may help you..

```
final Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

btn.setText(new StringBuilder(btn.getText().toString().trim()).reverse());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Check the test it say sin to "sin inverse" but your function will make it like "esrevni nis"